# initscr() is messing up display

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am new to C++ and ncurses. When I add `initscr()` to my code to allow user input to control the player, the display does not show when it starts and then when you press a button the display shows but it goes all weird. This only happens if I add `initscr()` to my `main()` method. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
using namespace std;

bool gameOver;
bool pressed;
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;
enum eDirection { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
eDirection dir;

void Setup() {
    gameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    fruitX = rand() % width;
    fruitY = rand() % height;
    score = 0;
}

void Draw() {
    system("clear");
    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (j == 0)
                cout << "#";
            if (i == y && j == x)
                cout << "O";
            else if (i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
                cout << "F";
            else
                cout << " ";

            if (j == width - 1)
                cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;
}

void Input() {
    switch (getch()) {
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameOver = true;
            break;
    }
}

void Logic() {
    switch (dir) {
        case LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
        case UP:
            y--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    //initscr();
    Setup();
    while(!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
    }
    //endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing curses with non-curses screen control and seeing the results of conflict between the libraries.

If you are going to use curses, just use that. Peruse the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) for information on doing it correctly. (The documentation there applies to most of **PDCurses** as well.)

tl;dr: Get rid of `system()` calls to do stuff to the screen, and use the `*addstr()` and `*printw()` functions to print output. Don’t forget to `[w]refresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/attrib.html uses ncurses and includes an example using clear().

Additional examples can be found at:
https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/
http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html
http://www.c-for-dummies.com/ncurses/source_code/index.php (examples)